# jQuery Form Plugin with live() in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, live

Has anyone had issues when using jQuery form plugin to provide file uploads in conjunction with jQuery live in IE?

It seems to function fine in FF but when trying it in IE, the submit isn't detected at all.

Example code below:

```
var options = {
    beforeSubmit: showRequest,
    success: showResponse,
    url: 'index.php?module=vacancies&action=upload',
    dataType: 'json'
};

$('#uploadCvForm').live('submit', function() {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
    return false;
});

$("#loading").ajaxStart(function(){
    $(this).show();
}).ajaxComplete(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});

function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
    var fileToUploadValue = $('input[name="document"]').fieldValue();
    if (!fileToUploadValue[0]) {
        $('input[name="document"]').addClass('validationError');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

function showResponse(data)  {
    if (data.status == 'failed') {

    }
    else {

    }
}
```

Comment: From the JavaScript you've provided you do not need the functionality of `.live()`, try replacing it with `.bind()`

Comment: The html for the form is created after the DOM is loaded, that's why I've had to use .live()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed; I moved the logic that handles the upload to within the dialog onOpen section which allowed me to use .submit() rather than .live('submit', function() ...